# In the Java install directory, why are there multiple java.exe files?

Tags: java, directory, installation

Just curious about the directory layout for the JDK . So there are two separate java.exe files  - one is in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin
```

and one is in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin
```

Why does there need to be two files ?  The motivation for this question arises from some challenge I'm having installing a program(SQL Developer).

Comment: Don't quote me here, but maybe one for JDK and one for JRE?

Comment: @Rogue - OK, so for practicality's sake I guess

Comment: I vote this up because given the disk sizes today I ever wonder why someone would want to only install the jre. A good answer to this one here might help me to understand this too.

Comment: Doesn't windowze has softlinks? This way if there is a JDK, it can just create a soft-link to the exe in the JRE folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between installing the `jdk` vs. the `jre`.

The `jdk` package is the developer package and includes tools such as the compiler (`javac`).

The `jre` package is the core runtime package, and includes the JVM / runtime environment / whatever you need to run software written in JVM languages.

Comment: But even if **only** a is installed (no JRE, no "public JRE") there are two copies of `java.exe` (and `javaw.exe`): one in `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and one in `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin`. I think that's what Adel is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Here a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html#A1097730) to the official Oracle documentation.

The binaries in `jdk/bin` and `jdk/jre/bin` are identical. According to the documentation, the `PATH` should point to `jdk/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/) to JDK 7 and JRE 7 Installation Guide

> If you want to run Java programs, but not develop them, download the JRE. If you want to develop Java applications, download the Java Development Kit, or JDK. The JDK includes the JRE, so you do not have to download both separately.